# Traverse through a map to get keys of val or val of keys

Tags: scala

I have a map below,but i need a function that needs to be able to return a list with following numbers if we pass "100" which is a key we pass in via arg

```
List(100, 102 , 106 , 107 , 111 , 112) <- example output
```

So essentially,add to a list if key(passed in) has value and if that value has a key

```
So given we pass in key of 100,
we add 100 to the list and the value is 102, so add that to the list
Then 102 is the new key, so add that to the list
for 102 the value is 107, so add 107 as well to the list...
and so on...



def returnList(key : String): List[String] = {
  Database
  List.empty
}
```

Comment: Did you mean for val Database to be a Map[String, List[String]]? Each key in a map is associated to one value. In the provided val Database, Database.get("100") yields "102". e.g. Did you want something more along the lines of Map("100", List("101", "102"))

Comment: first of all your Database Map has duplicate key i.e. 100 only the latest will be saved i.e. "100" -> "102" .

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  sorry took the duplicate key out

Comment: @dedpo  cant understand requirement , Please put some more explanation in details

Comment: @JavaCoder added some more details

Comment: @dedpo You said that "for 102 the value is 106" how 106 ? in database we seen "102" -> "107" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `iterate` until you run out of key values.

```
Iterator.iterate("100")(Database.getOrElse(_,"")).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).toList
```

This assumes that an empty string, `""`, is a good indicator of a value not found in the `Map`. If there is no good indicator value, you can always go with the `Option` wrapper. A little more verbose but exactly what `Option`s are good for.

```
Iterator.iterate(Option("100"))(opt => Database.get(opt.head))
        .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty) //stop at first None
        .flatten               //remove Option wrappers
        .toList                //List[String] = List(100, 102, 107, 112)
```

Comment: "Miserable excuse for a software engineer" I think you are too modest sir!
I will have to figure out all these short cuts to this elegant oneliner

Comment: thank you, does .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty) mean execute till end of a map essentially?

Comment: `Iterator.iterate()()` can, potentially, create an infinite collection.  After `Database` returns a value that is not also a key, that non-key value will be attempted as an index and `Database` will return the `OrElse` value (in the 1st example) or a `None` value (in the 2nd example). `takeWhile()` will turn a (potentially) infinite collection into a finite one by stopping at the first element that doesn't meet its requirements (in this case `nonEmpty`).

Answer (score 1):

```
val Database = Map(
  "100" -> "102",
  "101" -> "106",
  "102" -> "107",
  "103" -> "108",
  "104" -> "109",
  "105" -> "110",
  "106" -> "111",
  "107" -> "112",
  "108" -> "113",
  "109" -> "114",
  "110" -> "115"
)

def getStrangeListForKey(database: Map[String, String], key: String): List[String] = {
  def _getStrangeSetForKey(database: Map[String, String], key: String, acc: Set[String]): Set[String] = {
    database.get(key) match {
      case Some(value) => _getStrangeSetForKey(database, value, acc + value)
      case None => acc
    }
  }

  _getStrangeSetForKey(database, key, Set(key)).toList
}

getStrangeListForKey(Database, "100")
```